# How to handle supervision timeout for different android versions BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know the supervision timeout is internally set on BLE for android. But are there any hacks one can make?

I am thinking to create a custom timeout timer, with a `Task.Delay`and a `ContinueWith`combo and then clean it up if disconnection was successful within a certain timeframe that i set myself.

Is this approach something that could work or are there any other hacks/tricks to use to avoid lower supervision timeout for specific android versions?